# How can I substitute my software application for an HSM to work with PKCS?

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm

I am trying to replace HSM(s) with my software-only application and integrate with PKCS11. The problem I have with that is all of PKCS api functions deal with slots and tokens which are not a part of my software application. Are there examples out there that I can look up to see how a software application can be used to imitate an HSM and integrate with PKCS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with HSM's you have to deal with slots and tokens. You have to modify your software slightly to accommodate this.

There are 2 ways you can use the PKCS#11, `PKCS#11 Wrapper` or `PKCS#11 Provider`. The Wrapper is the api that calls the native functions of the HSM library (.dll or .so) directly. The Provider uses the Wrapper under the hood, but gives you the convenience of using it with Java `KeyStore` api.

Considering your case, the Wrapper might not be fit for you, because it involves writing new classes to integrate with the HSM. You could use the provider.

Java has very good documentation of the PKCS11 Provider [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html). There is also a very good third-party library called `IAIK`, [here](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core_Crypto_Toolkits/PKCS_11_Provider) is their provider documentation. Even though you use the Provider in your software application, trivial code changes are inevitable.

Where ever you have used the `KeyStore` api, you may have to make changes there. And initially, when your software loads, you have to load a configuration file for the PKCS11 provider that tells which slot number and the token to connect to.

IAIK has very good examples too, and their provider library is only free for development purposes.